# how does passing shared pointer by value and accepting as base class argument work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, polymorphism, shared-ptr

in this program :http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp

```
class chat_session
  : public chat_participant,
```

chat_session inherits chat_participant

in one of the calls a `shared_ptr` to `chat_session` is sent to the `join` method
`room_.join(shared_from_this());`

which is defined as

```
  void join(chat_participant_ptr participant)
```

so how does the example above translate to `particpant` being a base class pointer to the inherited class instance?

My understnading of base class pointer to inherited class instance is the from the **Virtual members**
example here

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

---edit---

An example would be great if somebody could explain how a pointer to base class can be defined in the function arguments even if we are not using shared_ptrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart pointers are supposed to behave like regular raw pointers *in this respect*. With raw pointers, you can have a function `foo()` like the one below:

```
void foo(B* pBase);
```

And - given a class `D` that derives from `B` - pass to it a pointer of type `D*`:

```
class D : public B { ... };
// ...
D obj;
foo(&obj); // OK!
```

This is simply how derived-to-base conversion works, and its fundamental for polymorphism. Now smart pointers are meant to emulate this mechanism, so that given:

```
void foo(shared_ptr<B> pBase);
```

You could do:

```
shared_ptr<D> pObj = make_shared<D>();
foo(pObj); // OK!
```

Technically, the way this behavior is achieved for the `shared_ptr` class template is to have a user-defined constructor template that carries out the implicit conversion:

```
template<class T> class shared_ptr {
public:
    // ...
    template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;
    // ...
};
```

This converting constructor will actually participate to overload resolution only if `Y` is convertible to `T`. § 20.7.2.2.1/17 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> *Requires*: The second constructor shall not participate in the overload resolution unless `Y*` is implicitly
>   convertible to `T*`.

This is typically achieved by using SFINAE constraints on the function template.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit conversion (by means of a non-explicit constructor) from `shared_ptr<T>` to `shared_ptr<U>` if and only if

- `U` is `void` or
- `U` is an accessible base class of `T`